# Is there a way to update nuget in Visual Studio 2013 in an offline machine?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget

I am running Visual Studio 2013 on a machine that is behind a firewall, not connected to the Internet.

I created a local folder on the machine and copied all packages that I might need to work with (`.nupkg` files).

In VS2013, I configured nuget by adding a local source for these packages.

The problem is: some of the packages require the latest version of nuget itself.
As far as I know, the only way I can update nuget, is to go to TOOLS>Extensions & Updates> Update > Visual Studio Gallery > Nuget

That only works if you have an active connection to the internet.

Is there a way I can download the latest version of nuget that is compatible with VS2013, and somehow install it or have nuget update itself based on what I downloaded?

I tried to look for answers but all the results talk about how to install nuget *packages* in offline mode, but not how to upgrade nuget itself.

Comment: write an app that [fetches version info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-client-sdk#list-package-versions) for your used packages and if a newer version s detected, let it [download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-client-sdk#download-a-package) the package and place it on your local directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to https://www.nuget.org/downloads, on the right hand side there are some downloads for VS2013 and VS2015's VSIX (Visual Studio extension).

If you want to go to the same source that that Visual Studio itself checks, that's marketplace.visualstudio.com. [This is my query for nuget, also filterting for VS2013](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=nuget&target=VS&category=All%20categories&vsVersion=vs2013&sortBy=Relevance). You can see that the official NuGet client is the first result. There's a download button there, to download the vsix.

Note however that the latest version of NuGet available for Visual Studio 2013 is NuGet verion 2.12. Many packages that need a higher version of NuGet. Looking at Entity Framework Core as an example, it needs NuGet 3.6. Any package using a SemVer2 multi-component prerelease label (for example `1.2.3-pre.4` vs `1.2.3-pre4`), will require NuGet 4.3. You will need to update to a newer version of Visual Studio if you need to use packages with these minimum NuGet version requirements.

Comment: That is exactly what I was expecting as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to make the machine connected for a short time to the internet and update nuget. Try also asking on the Microsoft TechNet forums. But I'd recommend just connect it shortly to the internet.